# How to use a Count window function to get a percentage?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Say I have the following table and values:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  context text
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('idea'), ('vote'), ('vote'), ('query'), ('vote');
```

I want to be able to find out what percentage of the rows in the table are equal to `vote` without using a subquery in the select statement (which correct me if I'm off on this, will re-calculate for every row in the result set).

I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT context, count(*) / count(*) OVER ()::DOUBLE PRECISION AS pct
FROM test
GROUP BY context
```

but having no success. I would hope to see something like:

`context_name` `pct_of_total` for each distinct context type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enumerator is count partitioned by context and the denominator is count without partition

```
select distinct
 context
,round( 100.0* count(1) over (partition by context) / count(1) over () ,2) as perc
from test
```